# Non portable CSS: button background images do not display in some mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile, less, portability

I have some HTML/CSS button-like components that display fine in most browsers and do not work in some.

More precisely, I'm trying to create some "buttons" that have a background image instead of text inside of them.

**The problem is that on some mobile devices, the images do not display. I could not make out a precise pattern as to when this fails.**

I'm hoping that expert eyes will be able to spot something non portable in the below code. Thanks for you help!

Note: I've already checked, the images files themselves are fine. Actually, they do work in isolation on all browsers, either in `<img>` tags or as backgrounds.

---

The desired output, working in most browsers (and all of the emulators on Chrome) looks like this:

[image]

And what I get when it does not work (only some mobile devices)

[image]

The HTML structure is as follows (3 variations of the same component):

```
<div class="gl_arrows">
    <div class="gl-btn_container gl-btn--left-arrow-anthra">
        <div class="gl-btn_text">Artiste précédent</div>
        <a href="#/pool/5554c64dd4c67a714bacda07/artist/traits-d-union" class="gl-btn_button"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="gl-btn_container gl-btn--rose-thumb">
        <div class="gl-btn_text" >Voter</div>
        <button class="gl-btn_button"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="gl-btn_container gl-btn--right-arrow-anthra">
        <div class="gl-btn_text">Artiste suivant</div>
        <a href="#/pool/5554c64dd4c67a714bacda07/artist/the-lemon-queen" class="gl-btn_button"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, each 'button' component is a composite of:

1. a container element
2. a span element, meant to hold the text of the button
3. the 'button' element itself, can be a `<button>` or `<a>`.

Finally, here is the LESS code I use to style this:

```
    @import "gl_base";
@import "gl_utils";

@gl-btn-diameter--xs: 50px;
@gl-btn-diameter--sm: 84px;
@gl-btn-diameter--lg: 96px;


// An element that contains the button and its text
.gl-btn_container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

// the text element of the button
.gl-btn_text {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-size: 10px;
  @media (min-width: @gl-w-lg) {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

// applied to <a> or <button> with no content (they will have a background image).
.gl-btn_button { // sizes the button.
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  height: @gl-btn-diameter--xs;
  width: @gl-btn-diameter--xs;

  @media (min-width: @gl-w-sm) {
    height: @gl-btn-diameter--sm;
    width: @gl-btn-diameter--sm;
  }
  @media (min-width: @gl-w-lg) {
    height: @gl-btn-diameter--lg;
    width: @gl-btn-diameter--lg;
  }

  text-align: center;

  border: none;
  padding: 0;

}

// mixin to add the image to the button.
.gl_btn_of-image(@url){
  display: inline-block;
  background: no-repeat url(@url) 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

// mixin that configures a whole button and its container
.gl_btn-config(@img; @color; @sel_img; @sel_color){

  .gl-btn_button {
    .gl_btn_of-image(@img); // add the background image
    &:active, &:focus, &:hover {
      .gl_btn_of-image(@sel_img);
    }
  }
  .gl-btn_text { // this styles the text element before the button itself.
    color: @color;
    &:active, &:focus,
    &:hover {
      color: @sel_color;
    }
  }

}

// these are some particular of these buttons.
.gl-btn--right-arrow-white {
  .gl_btn-config(@img: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bs-sncf-assets/logos/G%26C_B_demarrer_96.png"; @color: white;@sel_img: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bs-sncf-assets/logos/G%26C_B_demarrer_96.png"; @sel_color: white);
}

.gl-btn--left-arrow-anthra {
  .gl_btn-config(@img: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bs-sncf-assets/logos/G%26C_B_precedent_anthra_base_96.png"; @color: @gl_anthracite;@sel_img: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bs-sncf-assets/logos/G%26C_B_precedent_anthra_selection_96.png"; @sel_color: @gl_anthracite);
}

.gl-btn--right-arrow-anthra {
  .gl_btn-config(@img: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bs-sncf-assets/logos/G%26C_B_suivant_anthra_base_96.png"; @color: @gl_anthracite;@sel_img: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bs-sncf-assets/logos/G%26C_B_suivantva_anthra_selection_96.png"; @sel_color: @gl_anthracite);
}

.gl-btn--rose-thumb {
  .gl_btn-config(@img: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bs-sncf-assets/logos/G%26C_B_vote_base_96.png"; @color: @gl_rose;@sel_img: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bs-sncf-assets/logos/G%26C_B_vote_selection_96.png"; @sel_color: @gl_rose--dark);

  &.gl-btn--disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
    .gl_btn-config(@img: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bs-sncf-assets/logos/G%26C_B_vote_base_96.png"; @color: @gl_rose;@sel_img: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bs-sncf-assets/logos/G%26C_B_vote_base_96.png"; @sel_color: @gl_rose);
  }
}


.gl-btn_container--color(@color){
  .gl-btn_text {
    color: @gl_anthracite;
  }
}

.gl-btn_container--anthra {
  .gl-btn_container--color(@gl_anthracite);
}
```

The `@imports` only import some variables (colors and screen sizes), nothing critical or complex.

Comment: On which devices your code doesn't work?

Comment: Some old iPhones, some old Android browsers. iPhone 4s and Galaxy Note 3 on Android browser.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with the compiled `CSS`?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova: here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/zcv6Ls9k/ . I indented it, but there's a lot of things you won't want to see. Unfortunately it seems the relevant CSS got spread all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually an answer, but it's too long to post it as a comment. It might help you solve your issue, though.

If I were you I would go through the CSS files and look for relatively new properties and selectors which might not work in older browsers/OS: `background-size`, etc. Incorrect ordering of attributes of some properties may cause not proper rendering of elements in older browser. Such as `background`'s attributes:

- background-color
- background-image
- background-repeat
- background-attachment
- background-position

This is the correct ordering, but I saw that you have set it this way:

`background: no-repeat url("https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bs-sncf-assets/logos/G%26C_B_vote_base_96.png") 0 0;`

Nowadays, browsers are smart enough to understand and properly render almost anything you type. But older browsers expect explicitly to tell them  want you want to render in the way/order they're programmed to.

This might be a something you can start with.